# All of my files have disappeared from ubuntu one

Tags: ubuntu-one

I had photographs and documents stored online but everything has gone, I have logged into the website in my browser but there is no sign of anything. Its not a problem as I backed up 99% of the files to dvd but I am a bit concerned about how safe this service is before  commit to it, are the files simply lost ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 11.04 your files are moved to the trash rather than deleted by Ubuntu One. If you are on a different version of Ubuntu then we may be able to recover your files if they were in your Ubuntu One folder. Please contact support at https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact

Ubuntu One should never delete your files without being told to do so. One scenario where files are deleted is when there is a new install of Ubuntu and the ~/.local/share/ubuntuone folder from an old backup is copied to the computer. There is an [FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/SettingUpAnExistingAccount) about this. Other times when files are being synced between multiple computers, there is confusion about what happens when you delete all the synced files from one computer. This will delete files from the server and all connected computers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joshua, I think this bit covers what has happened to me :-

"Other times when files are being synced between multiple computers, there is confusion about what happens when you delete all the synced files from one computer. This will delete files from the server and all connected computers." 

 Basically I was trying out the latest kernel and Gnome 3 on 11.04 on my desktop computer, I expected some corruption whist doing this so put 11.04 and Ubuntu One on my Mrs' netbook at the same time, I guess this is where things started going awry!  

Appreciate the insight pal.